# Making LinearLayout with ListView scrollable

Tags: java, android, listview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout that looks something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.EnrolStudentFormActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view
        android:layout_width="match_pare
        android:layout_height="wrap_cont
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

With a few `ImageView`s, `TextInputLayout`s and `TextInputEditText`s in between. I want to make this layout scrollable. I tried to make it scrollable with `ScrollView` and `NestedScrollView`, but both of them messed the `ListView` up.

I am also changing the `ListView` contents dynamically and I have a few `TextInputEditText`s inside `TextInputLayout`s inside the `ListView`. Resizing the `ListView` doesn't help much, and I cannot click on the `TextInputEditText` inside the `ListView`. It seems that the `ScrollView` captures the touch input.

Are there any workarounds that will let me have a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` or make the linear layout scrollable while making the `TextInputEditText` inside the `ListView` usable?

Comment: Can you add your design issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView` and add `NestedScrollView` on top:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android="
http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:http="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.EnrolStudentFormActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />>

</LinearLayout>
```

and finally in your code add:

```
RecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem! Also, the adapter needs to be changed. Just pointing it out in case anyone else has the same problem